# Sql query call fails if no record is found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, database

I am trying to fetch a string from sql db. I have the following query:

```
select DISTINCT HARDWARE.NAME
from HARDWARE INNER JOIN
     HARDWARE_LINKING
     on HARDWARE.ID = HARDWARE_LINKING.ID
where HARDWARE_LINKING.EXTERNALID='5528752'.
```

Now when there is no record against any id the function call fails. 
here is my function code that I am calling to fetch data:

```
public String search(String externalId) {
  String SQL = "select DISTINCT HARDWARE.NAME  from HARDWARE INNER JOIN HARDWARE_LINKING on HARDWARE.ID = HARDWARE_LINKING.ID where HARDWARE_LINKING.EXTERNALID=?";
        Object[] input = new Object[] {externalId};
        String name = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL,input, String.class);
        return name;
}
```

Is there any way I can return a default value? and sometimes there are multiple values return but I want only single string value to be returned, Is that possible? Thankyou in advance

Comment: you could catch the exception and to get only one record put limi 0,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to put the default into the query itself.  Use an aggregation function and `COALESCE()`:

```
select coalesce(h.NAME, '<default value>') as NAME
from HARDWARE h INNER JOIN
     HARDWARE_LINKING hl
     on h.ID = hl.ID
where hl.EXTERNALID = '5528752';
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns one row, so this would seem to be more what you are looking for.

Also note that I put table aliases into the query.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: `coalesce(min(h.NAME), '<default value>') as NAME`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check name for null or isEmpty and then decide if you should return the name from the query or a default value.

```
if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()){
    return name;
} else {
    return "default";
}
```